# Can't save files or open programs in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, readonly

I rebooted my Kali Linux which was working fine, but now most of the programs won't start, I can't save anything to any of the partitions, including the Kali Instalation partition. Whenever I try to open a program or `aptget update` or `apt-get upgrade` I get the error:

> Cannot override file. Read only file system

When starting Kali, I get the error:

> Recovering journal
>   Contains file system with errors
>   fsck exited with status code 1

I have tried:

1. `fsck -fy /dev/sda1`
2. **apt-get:**

   > sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get clean
   >   sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get upgrade

**UPDATE**

**fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c6e6d302-588b-46aa-bd30-fcc34e434c16 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=0d42340e-54c8-42cf-ad82-c7ef7b7fc75b none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Comment: If you don't understand the basics of running a Linux system please consider whether Kali is right for you. It's not designed or intended for beginners.

Comment: You start from somewhere then learn. Better than avoiding it just because you don't understand it. No one starts all-knowing @roaima. I totally don't agree with you. You once were a novice like me.

Comment: I totally agree that one should start somewhere. I believe the phrase is "walk before you run". If you want to learn then I would (still) strongly recommend Ubuntu, Mint, or Fedora as beginner-friendly options. When you are more comfortable with the systems you will be far better placed to move to a specialist distribution such as Kali.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Live-Linux, and make the filesystem-check from there.

If fsck.ext4 is not working, check your harddrive with [smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Answer (score -3):

I once had a similar problem. You should check your *[fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)* file.

If there aren't any issues with your *fstab* file (all partitions and devices are properly configured), and you still get this error message, it is probable that something went wrong with your disk partitioning (wrong filesystem for example, the default for linux is [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4))

fstab should look a bit like this:

```
# <file system> <dir>           <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sdaX       /               ext4    defaults        0       1
/dev/sdaY       /mount/path        ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Where sdaX is the partition you have your linux installed. It has to be mounted on root catalog.

**EDIT** 
I don't know what those UUID mean, so try `fsck -f` without specifying any filesystems, it should check them all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Szymon Wieczorek. I just posted my fstab content

Comment: Try adding *defaults* to your main partition options (the one with linux). Also the *errors=remount-ro* mean that if there is an error when mounting filesystem, it will mount as a read-only.